# Connecting a VirtualBox VM to the internet

Tags: virtualbox, virtualbox-networking

I have built a Ubuntu Server 14.04.5 LTS server on a VirtualBox environment (VMware .vmdk format) to host an older LAMP app (CATS). Windows 10 desktop host.

Right now, can only get this VM accessing the internet with NAT networking. One-way traffic, to get updates. I need to generate some URL so I can interact with the web server locally, on this laptop.

Further (optionally) I would like to expose this VM-based webserver to the web, and let there be external access. I read that I need to use VirtualBox's Host Only networking, discussed in the [VirtualBox docs here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly).

**Two questions:**

1. How can I at least get local access to this web server which is located on my VM? I understand that i will need port forwarding going, and I can't even get my static IP address to work with VirtualBox...
2. How can I allow external access to this vm-based web server? (optional, nice to have).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I did the same thing using VMWare disk on Virtualbox and it wasn't so pretty!

Comment: you have misread the document, host-only is exactly what is says - only the host and VM on that host can communicate `and the virtual machines cannot talk to the world outside the host since they are not connected to a physical networking interface.`

Comment: the networking part you need is https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward - 6.3.1. Configuring port forwarding with NAT. and then you port forward it to your host from router